# vkQueueSubmit blocks when using timeline semaphores

Tags: c++, vulkan

I need to run a function on CPU between two GPU batches. For this I use timeline semaphores. As far as I know, vkQueueSubmit does not block. However, it blocks when I submit these GPU batches:

```
uint64_t host_wait = timeline;
uint64_t host_signal = ++timeline;

uint64_t wait0 = timeline;
uint64_t signal0 = ++timeline;
uint64_t wait1 = timeline;
uint64_t signal1 = ++timeline;

VkPipelineStageFlags wait_mask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;

VkTimelineSemaphoreSubmitInfo sp_submit0 = {
    .sType                     = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_TIMELINE_SEMAPHORE_SUBMIT_INFO,
    .waitSemaphoreValueCount   = 1,
    .pWaitSemaphoreValues      = &wait0,
    .signalSemaphoreValueCount = 1,
    .pSignalSemaphoreValues    = &signal0,
};
VkSubmitInfo submit0 = {
    .sType                = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO,
    .pNext                = &sp_submit0,
    .waitSemaphoreCount   = 1,
    .pWaitSemaphores      = &timeline_semaphore,
    .pWaitDstStageMask    = &wait_mask,
    .signalSemaphoreCount = 1,
    .pSignalSemaphores    = &timeline_semaphore,
};

VkTimelineSemaphoreSubmitInfo sp_submit1 = {
    .sType                     = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_TIMELINE_SEMAPHORE_SUBMIT_INFO,
    .waitSemaphoreValueCount   = 1,
    .pWaitSemaphoreValues      = &wait1,
    .signalSemaphoreValueCount = 1,
    .pSignalSemaphoreValues    = &signal1,
};
VkSubmitInfo submit1 = {
    .sType                = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO,
    .pNext                = &sp_submit1,
    .waitSemaphoreCount   = 1,
    .pWaitSemaphores      = &timeline_semaphore,
    .pWaitDstStageMask    = &wait_mask,
    .commandBufferCount   = 1,
    .pCommandBuffers      = &command_buffer,
    .signalSemaphoreCount = 1,
    .pSignalSemaphores    = &timeline_semaphore,
};

VkSubmitInfo infos[2] = { submit0, submit1 };
vkQueueSubmit(queue, 2, infos, fence);
// here vkQueueSubmit blocks the thread

WaitSemaphore(timeline_semaphore, host_wait);
some_function();
SignalSemaphore(timeline_semaphore, host_signal);
```

It is blocking for seconds without return, I think this is something like a deadlock. In the debugger, I saw SleepEx function call from vkQueueSubmit: vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddrSG -> ... -> SleepEx.

But vkQueueSubmit does not block in this sample (combined batch):

```
uint64_t host_wait = timeline;
uint64_t host_signal = ++timeline;

uint64_t wait1 = timeline;
uint64_t signal1 = ++timeline;

VkPipelineStageFlags wait_mask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;

VkTimelineSemaphoreSubmitInfo sp_submit1 = {
    .sType                     = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_TIMELINE_SEMAPHORE_SUBMIT_INFO,
    .waitSemaphoreValueCount   = 1,
    .pWaitSemaphoreValues      = &wait1,
    .signalSemaphoreValueCount = 1,
    .pSignalSemaphoreValues    = &signal1,
};
VkSubmitInfo submit1 = {
    .sType                = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO,
    .pNext                = &sp_submit1,
    .waitSemaphoreCount   = 1,
    .pWaitSemaphores      = &timeline_semaphore,
    .pWaitDstStageMask    = &wait_mask,
    .commandBufferCount   = 1,
    .pCommandBuffers      = &command_buffer,
    .signalSemaphoreCount = 1,
    .pSignalSemaphores    = &timeline_semaphore,
};

VkSubmitInfo infos[1] = { submit1 };
vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, infos, fence);

WaitSemaphore(timeline_semaphore, host_wait);
some_function();
SignalSemaphore(timeline_semaphore, host_signal);
```

Why vkQueueSubmit blocks in the first code sample? What are the possible causes of this problem?
I use Vulkan 1.2 (SDK 1.2.135) on Windows 10 and Radeon RX 570 (driver 20.4.2).

EDIT: When I add a command buffer to `submit0`, vkQueueSubmit will not block. Is it a bug in the driver?

Comment: `vkQueueSubmit` is not a fast call; it's always going to take up a non-trivial amount of time. So is it "blocking" or is it simply taking longer than you would prefer?

Comment: @NicolBolas It is blocking because the first code sample is equivalent to the second, which is not blocking.

Comment: So you don't actually *know* if it is doing the thing that is generally considered to be "blocking"; it's that the code isn't as fast as you think it ought to be. It is hardly surprising that two batches take more time to submit than one.

Comment: "*if I add another command buffer to `submit0`,*" But that wouldn't be "another" CB, because you didn't add a CB to `submit0` at all. It's an empty batch.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is blocking for seconds without return, I think this is something like a deadlock. In the debugger, I saw SleepEx function call from vkQueueSubmit: vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddrSG -> ... -> SleepEx.

Comment: "*I saw SleepEx function call from vkQueueSubmit*" You could have just said that to begin with. I mean, that is how you know it's blocking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Doing something odd like submitting a batch with no work is far more likely to be the cause.
>
> The spec doesn’t have performance requirements. The fact that something is legal does not make it a good idea. Broadly speaking, if there are two ways to do a thing, do it the obvious way. And sending an empty batch isn’t exactly obvious

https://community.khronos.org/t/vkqueuesubmit-blocks-when-using-timeline-semaphores/105704/2